# SSIS script component. Value comparison then transformation

Tags: vb.net, ssis, script-component

I'm trying to learn how to use script component.  I'm trying to take a value, 'Gender', and then check to see whether it is "M" or "F".  If it is M then change value to G and if F then change value to L.  My input column is gender and my output column is genderChange I'm just going to have it print to a flat file.  I'm aware that there are transformations already built into SSIS but I really want to use script component.

This is my code that I have

```
Dim arr() As String = Row.Gender.Split(","c)
        Dim iReadingCount As Integer = 1
         Dim convertVal As String = " "


        For i As Integer = 0 To arr.Length - 1
            With Output0Buffer


                .AddRow()

                convertVal = Convert.ToString(Row.Gender)
                If (convertVal Is "M") Then
                     .genderChange = "G"
                  End If
                If (convertVal Is "F") Then
                    .genderChange = "L"
                 End If

                 iReadingCount += 1
            End With
        Next
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: What you don't specify is that you are creating an asynchronous component (1 input row != 1 output row). The `Gender` is going to be a CSV ("M,M,F") and for each value in that list, your desire is to create a row and have the value translated. Is this an accurate assessment of your intention?

Comment: Yeah,that's what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, the vb.net syntax is wrong here:

```
If (convertVal Is "M") Then
                     .genderChange = "G"
                  End If
                If (convertVal Is "F") Then
                    .genderChange = "L"
                 End If
```

One correct way to do this would be:

```
If convertVal.Equals("M") Then
                     .genderChange = "G"
                  End If
                If convertVal.Equals("F") Then
                    .genderChange = "L"
                 End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help with the syntax.

Comment: Please close this question by clicking the checkmark to the top left of the answer.